# Loading data from XML file into table using java

Tags: java, xml, oracle

I have data in a XML file. The format of the XML file is like this

Code:

```
<employees>
<employee>
<name>rgoti</name>
<empno>2</empno>
….
….
<employee>

<employee>
<name>sganee</name>
<empno>3</empno>
….
….
<employee>

….
….
</employees>
```

I want to load this data into the Oracle database using Java.How to design and create table and data types for saving this xml in table?.

Comment: Are you closing the `<employee>` tag somewhere?

Comment: Do you want to store the entire XML document in a single column?  If so, just use an `XMLType` column.  Or do you want to parse the XML document and store the data in a relational table?  If you want to store the data in a relational table, does the table already exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is too generic to gather a good answer. Common steps:

- define your employee table with an unique primary key
- define your employee class in java
- convert your xml in your java model (for example using jaxb)
- persist your model (with prepare statement or batch or persistence framework).